# User ID does not pick up when creating a new model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have set up the correct logic for the `User` and `Course` logic code. Here are my files that I currently have:

**app/models/course.rb**:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :course
end
```

**app/models/user.rb** (uses Devise):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :omniauthable
  has_many :courses
end
```

**db/migrate/...create_courses.rb**:

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.string :course, limit: 300
      t.text :description
      t.string :location
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :courses, :course, unique: true
    add_index :courses, :description
  end
end
```

When I create a new object for `course`, I get the following output:

1 error prohibited this article from being saved:

- User **must exist**

Stack trace of the problem:

```
Started POST "/courses" for 75.108.207.135 at 2016-07-22 22:33:28 -0500
Cannot render console from 75.108.207.135! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by CoursesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+RSKtrUI2jQ5DcXcndw7Lb9PN+mi6FJxGC3zX8oBLTnZdFeUTzTgZGc84V7onkW2UeNPTO2pHJ9cV2vx9yLjFQ==", "course"=>{"course"=>"Hello world", "description"=>"Hi", "location"=>"Hi"}, "commit"=>"Add Course"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering courses/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered courses/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 181ms (Views: 176.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

**app/controllers/courses_controller.rb**:

```
def create
    @course = Course.new(course_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.save
        format.html { redirect_to @course }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @course }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessible_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Is there something I left out during the model creation or messed it up completely?

Comment: Why does the validation in your Course model validate the presence of course? Course is the object, not a field of the object. Shouldn't you be validating the presence of user?

Comment: please add the course create method

Comment: `Course validates_presence_of :course` - wtf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough to know exactly what's going on without the CourseController#create method -- but what you'll want to be doing there is using one of the methods added by has_many to the user object.

Something to the effect of:

`user.courses.build(params[:course])` or `user.course.create(params[:course])`

Both build and create are available off of the collection.

Of course, Rails Guides has more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Comment: @RodrigoArgumedo: read the full answer. The guess here is the correct one.